# SwiftUI and UIKit interfacing with UIViewController requirements in older APIs

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

The scenario:

I have a simple SwiftUI view that looks like this:

```
struct AuthView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: handleLogin) {
                Text("Login to twitter")
            }
        }
    }

    private func handleLogin() {
        // do login stuff here
    }
}
```

Now ideally in the `handleLogin` function I would simply perform an OAuth request and handle logging in, etc. However, I am using a library I found on GitHub for demo purposes.

This library has a method `authorize(callBackUrl: URL, presentingController: UIViewController)` which when called presents a safari controller which allows the user to login to twitter. However, to call `authorize` you need to pass in a controller which conforms to `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate`. From my current basic understanding is that `View` type from SwiftUI isn't a view controller and moreover could not conform to the `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate` since it's a struct.

I looked at the [Interfacing with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) tutorial from Apples site, and they seem to create a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` type and then from the `View` type return this "controller" in the `body` of the `View`. This allows them to use PageViewController from UIKit. However, this isn't entirely the use case I have or need. I simply need to be able to somehow convert my simple `View` into a `UIViewController`. Would `UIHostingController` be the thing to use here, and if so, how would this dependency be injected or should the view even know/use a controller?

Mostly my confusion lies on not yet knowing what the best practices are for SwiftUI. The `View` type seems to replace the use of `UIViewController` in UIKit, but then how does the conversion work when interfacing with UIKit?

If anyone has any ideas or would like to discuss this I'd appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Probably this is a situation where the library you are using needs to change; Does it need a `UIViewController` or does it need an `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate`?  Asking for the former that conforms to the latter when it just needs the latter is probably a poor design.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to solve this, but you might get inspiration with the following.

Just to give you some context. I'm creating a fast prototype to implement Uber Authorization and I achieved it like this:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
// 
//  Created by Daniel Tello on 05/11/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Daniel Tello. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI
import UberCore

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: uberLogin) {
            Text("Uber")
            }
        }
    }
}

func uberLogin() {
    let scopes: [UberScope] = [.profile, .places, .request]
    let presentingView = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
    let loginManager = LoginManager(loginType: .native)

    loginManager.login(requestedScopes: scopes, presentingViewController: presentingView) { (accessToken, error) -> () in
        if accessToken != nil {
           NSLog("Got an AccessToken!")
        } else {
            // Error
            if let error = error {
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                NSLog("An Unknown Error Occured")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```